# Changing Terraform file using hclwrite in golang

Tags: go

Further to the post I put [Regex pattern to match terraform module code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61375395/regex-pattern-to-match-terraform-module-code) the suggestion was to look at golang's hclwrite module if we want to do surgical writes to the terraform file.

I invested some time to learn go and rewrote the python script in go. The script covers the initial part where it looks for file with the string 'module' in a terraform file. Since hclwrite functions ask for byte array I also converted the file contents to byte array.

we need to grab a terraform block starting with module and then write it back with its corresponding resource elements.To that I query the dictionary for module and then write back the resource. How do we do this using hclwrite?
Here are some references I used:
1.Example https://xuanwo.io/2020/04/13/get-started-with-hcl2/
2. Package for hcl syntax https://godoc.org/github.com/hashicorp/terraform/vendor/github.com/hashicorp/hcl/v2/hclsyntax#ParseConfig

Change

```
module mymodule {

}
To resource resource_name {
}
```

The code I wrote so far in go

```
func main() {
    var text string = "module"
    var dirpath = "<path to the files>/*.tf"
    //Get the terraform files in the directory and select files with string 'module'
    matches, _ := filepath.Glob(dirpath)
    for _, match := range matches {
        if IsExist(text, match) {
            fmt.Println(match)
            var chunk []byte

            file, err := os.Open(match)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err.Error())
            }
            defer file.Close()
            reader := bufio.NewReader(file)
            buffer := bytes.NewBuffer(make([]byte, 0))
            // var chunk []byte
            var eol bool
            var str_array []string
            for {
                if chunk, eol, err = reader.ReadLine(); err != nil {
                    break
                }
                buffer.Write(chunk)
                if !eol {
                    str_array = append(str_array, buffer.String())
                    buffer.Reset()
                }
            }

            if err == io.EOF {
                err = nil
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the text after "Change" supposed to be an example of what you want to do? Could you explain better with some detailed examples?

Comment: Thanks for responding.Yes the Text after change is what I want to do. Grab a terraform file, inspect a block like module and import/parse it using hclwrite. Once done.. make surgical changes and write/change it back in the original file.
Example:
module "mymodule" {
 name = "mymodule"
 version = "4.0.0"
}
May be change the above to
resource "resource_type" "myname" {
  policy ="policy-name"
  policy-arn = "my-policy-arn"
}

Comment: Could you please put the example in the original question, so that you can format it and better understood ?

Comment: Please close this posting. I was able to figure out how to do this on python itself and will post the solution on the other python posting I opened.